# How to push values into Object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an Object like this.

```
var myObj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  }
}
```

I know to add an entry like this.

```
myObj['model']='XUV';
```

but I want to add an entry inside the cars object (adding new 'Audi' car as car4) 
Can you show me how to add this?

Final output should be like.

```
 var myObj = {
      "name":"John",
      "age":30,
      "cars": {
        "car1":"Ford",
        "car2":"BMW",
        "car3":"Fiat",
        "car4":"Audi"
      }

}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I would name it as literal object, not json.

Comment: Using an object for the list of cars seems wrong. I'd suggest changing that to an array and then using `myObj.cars.push( 'Audi' );`

Answer (score 1):

just

```
myObj.cars["car4"] = "Audi";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `cars` object first and then assign a new `key-value` there so use `myObj.cars.car4 = 'Audi'` or with `[]` i.e, `myObj.cars['car4'] = 'Audi'`.

```js
var myObj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  }
}
myObj.cars.car4 = 'Audi';
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

**2017 answer: Object.assign()**

```
var obj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  }
};

Object.assign(obj.cars, {car4: "Audi"});
```

**2018 object spread operator {...}**

```
var obj = {
      "name":"John",
      "age":30,
      "cars": {
        "car1":"Ford",
        "car2":"BMW",
        "car3":"Fiat"
      }
    };

obj.cars = { ...obj.cars, car4: "Audi" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is, in my opinion, a badly built JSON. I would use array instead of a named property `"car" + someIndex`

```js
var myObj =
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "brand":"Ford" },
        { "brand":"BMW" },
        { "brand":"Fiat" }
    ]
}
myObj.cars.push({ "brand":"Renault" });
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add new property to a property multiple ways

1. `myObj['cars']['car4'] = 'Audi';`
2. `myObj['cars'].car4 = 'Audi';`
3. `myObj.cars['car4'] = 'Audi';`
4. `myObj.cars.car4 = 'Audi';`
5. Object.assign():

   `Object.assign(myObj.cars, {car4: 'Audi'});`
6. new ECMA 7 expand operator (`...`):

   `myObj.cars = { ...myObj.cars, car4: 'Audi' }`
7. Using Lodash `_ = require('lodash')`:

   `_.set(myObj, ['cars', 'car4'], 'Audi');`

`lodash.js` can also create property of new property too:

```
_.set(myObj, ['newProp', 'newCar', 'newBrand'], 'Think');
```